# A baby zombie jumped onto a zombie and rode it, is this a glitch?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I have no mods and it is my Xbox-360 and the zombies didn’t spawn that way. Is this a glitch?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a new feature. Baby zombies can ride anything(I think).  I’m pretty sure I read it in the change log.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you were more certain and had a link to the change log. EDIT: Just noticed that it's a duplicate question anyway.